# Set fields in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When creating a new Person, how do I set its fields that are not included in the new.html.erb form?

Here is the controller and form:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @account = Account.find_by_id(params[:account_id])
        organization = @account.organizations.primary.first
        location = organization.locations.primary.first
        @person = location.persons.build    
    end

    def create
        @person = Person.new(params[:person])
        if @person.save
            flash[:success] = "Person added successfully"
            redirect_to account_path(params[:account_id])
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end


<h2>Account: <%= @account.organizations.primary.first.name %></h2>

<%= form_for @person do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.label :email1 %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email1 %><br />
    <%= f.label :home_phone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :home_phone %><br />
    <%= f.submit "Add person" %>

<% end %>
```

Here are the models:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :organization

    has_many :persons, :as => :linkable
    has_one :address, :as => :addressable

    scope :primary, where('locations.primary_location = ?', true)

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :linkable, :polymorphic => true

end
```

The association method @person = location.persons.build works fine in the Rails Console.  It sets the 'linkable_id' field to 1 and the 'linkable_type' field to 'Location'.  However, after submitting the form the Person is created but these two fields are left blank.

Any help with this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are building the person object in the new action. You have to build the same in the create action as well..

```
def create
  # location = Calculate location here
  @person = location.persons.build(params[:person])
  if @person.save
    flash[:success] = "Person added successfully"
    redirect_to account_path(params[:account_id])
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the params send by the form `location.persons.build(params[:person])`

Comment: How do I calculate the location from the form submission?

Comment: You have to set the location information in the form using hidden variables like this: f.hidden_field :linkable_id

Comment: I added <%= f.hidden_field :location_id, value => @person.locations.location_id %> to the form but I am getting the following error now just trying to render the form: undefined local variable or method `value' for #<#<Class:0x1a04dc8>:0x19fea50>

Comment: I got it.  I used :linkable_id for the hidden field name as you recommended.  Also, I was using value instead of :value by mistake.  Thanks for you help!